# Does adding many -isystem include directives slow down the compilation process significantly?

Tags: c++, compilation, clang

For our software project, we have around 15 third party library dependencies. We suppress the warnings in these third party libraries using the -isystem include directive.

Our software project consists of more than 10 executables and libraries, each having dependencies on a subset of the third party libraries. We compile with clang on mac.

An easy way to disable all third party warnings for all projects in our build system is to include all third party libraries in all projects with -isystem.

The alternative is to separately define for each of our projects the -isystem directive. This is more work to set up and will blow up the configurations of all project files, but only the third party libraries that are actually used are included.

I'd prefer to go with the first option because it's not much work, but I am not sure if this will significantly slow down the compilation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flag will slowdown only standard headers search because prior each standard header is found it will also search it in your directories. So, that it depends on how many such directories you add and how many standard headers you use. For each standard header the impact will be a summ of:

```
time ls YOUR_DIR >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

for each your added directory.